# Slide the popup in libgdx not work

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to develop a libgdx game. i want to implement a selection screen. Till now i have implemented horizontal scrollpane and it is working fine.
Now i want to implement scrolling on the click on the button. You can check the image attached.
   [image]

Comment: skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json")); the give a error file not found exception..

Comment: Main problem is I do not know how to slide the popup in libgdx game.. please help me and give me answer..

Comment: Do you have problems with skin ? have you checked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182844/default-skin-libgdx

Comment: how to translate animation in libgdx.. please help me..

Comment: please give me answer ya suggestion.

Comment: please provide the code you write so far so can be reviewed.

Comment: I want to somthing like this...    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_8WSbB0WQQ

Comment: The question is not clear. Provide some code to clear what is not working .

Comment: thanks but I find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the answer look this link https://github.com/krustnic/HorizontalSlidingPane

Answer (score 0):

Try instead to use json pack

This works for me:

```
_skin = new Skin();
    TextureAtlas buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("images/buttons.pack");
    _skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    _textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    _textButtonStyle.font = _game.getFont();
    _textButtonStyle.up = _skin.getDrawable("button-orange");
    _textButtonStyle.down = _skin.getDrawable("button-blue");
```

buttons.pack:

```
buttons.png
size: 234,195
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
button-orange
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 0
  size: 236, 67
  split: 25, 25, 14, 14
  orig: 236, 67
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
button-blue
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 67
  size: 236, 67
  split: 25, 25, 14, 14
  orig: 236, 67
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
button-navy
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 134
  size: 236, 67
  split: 25, 25, 14, 14
  orig: 236, 67
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

Comment: this answer is clickable in the button and change the button image.. but i Want to slide the button or popup. how to sliding the image ya popup ya button..

Comment: Can you give an example of an image that you want?

Comment: example .. any car game car can be slide to choose and play .. in the same way i want to slide the car ya popup in libgdx game ..

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need a carousel. I added two buttons on the stage (right / left) and as many pictures as necessary to show the objects. When you click in the render method, I asked in a cycle through the objects position setPosition - visually carousel was obtained. If necessary, i will gladly share the code

Comment: but when i click the button than how to slide the image.. Example any Car Racing game when choose the car, slide the screen and choose the car. My problem is how to slide the car image in libgdx.

Comment: You should add this image to the stage as an actor(yourstage.add(yourimage)). To change the position, you must use the method setPosition(yourimage.setPosition(yourX, yourY))

Answer (score 0):

Try in create method

```
yourImage = new Image(new Texture("images/image.png"));
stage.add(yourImage);
```

Try in render method

```
 yourImage.setPosition(yourX, yourY)
```

Comment: thanks but this is not my problem solution. my problem is how to slide ya translate animation in the image in LibGDX click the buttion.

Comment: Look here(https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests), maybe find something worthwhile